# VsCode Source Control Missing Necessary Options

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository

I recently tried to link my GitHub to Visual Studio Code, and have run into a weird problem which I can't find a solution to. When I look in the source control tab, it only shows 'initialize repository' and 'publish to github' options, and not the 'open folder' and 'clone repo' option that show up in the tutorials. Is there a way to solve this, or am I doing something wrong? I'm running the newest version of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

The Source Control pane offers different options depending on whether you have opened a folder (left picture) or not (right picture):

[image: Source control]

Comment: ok, wait, so every type of file counts? even the ones that aren't cloned from github? So the solution is: close all files and clone the repo?

Comment: Ok, so I closed all files, and now it shows 'add folder to workspace' in source control, not the things your image shows

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you aware that (source control aside) VS Code can optionally work in folder/workspace context? https://i.imgur.com/yhG6PNK.png